# Parametrized Wget FTP recursive download

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, wget

I am trying to make a simple script in order to create automatic FTP backups reading domain, user and password from a CSV. I am using Wget command like this, and if i launch it from console, it works out of the box:

```
wget -r -P ./directory ftp://domain.com --ftp-user=myuser --ftp-password=mypassword
```

The problem occurs when i parameterize that command into a bash script to use it for many websites:

```
#!/bin/sh

    #Read CSV.
    while IFS=, read dominio usuario contrasenya
    do
        echo "Realizando Backup de: $dominio $usuario $contrasenya"

        #Crear el backup del sitio web.
        wget -r -P ./ ftp://"$dominio" --ftp-user="$usuario" --ftp-password="$contrasenya"

    done < sitios-coma.csv
```

It returns 'Incorrect login'.

Anyone knows what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the username/password are good? You could check it by running `bash -x yourscript.sh` and ensure the credentials are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Yes, credentials are OK, but script is unable to get connected. Using it directly in console works good.

Comment: You didn't say if a single wget fails or every one fails.

Comment: All Wgets are failing inside script, even if i execute `bash-x myscript.sh` i can see the variables printed in the command. These variables are printed correctly but command is executed with 'Incorrect login'. I thing special characters are inside the variables or something similar.

Comment: @walolinux Do your passwords contain any shell special characters? They may be escaped.

Comment: @Kadir Letters, numbers, and sometimes, asterisks. All are legible characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [downloading file from ftp server via wget fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617695/downloading-file-from-ftp-server-via-wget-fails)